# Wordpress Align sidebar to the main container

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

I question whether it is possible to sidebar is aligned to my main content without using margin-top? If so, how?

So it is now
[image]

And so it should be
[image]

Comment: Not with how the HTML is currently structured. You would need to restructure the HTML to move the sidebar in a container alongside the main content.

Answer (score 0):

you would need to move your html and you can also try position and top